# CSS image draw style 'border'

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry for the unexplaining title...but I would like to ask how to achive these sort-of borders as are in this website/template [here](https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/62261.html) - as you can see all the divs have this art style transition, tried to look up the code but can't seem to figure it out. Thank you.
 [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vE30.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific than pointing to a reference link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of pseudo elements like `:before` or `:after` for the `div` you want to apply such borders to.

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #19354b;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://ld-prestashop.template-help.com/prestashop_62261/themes/theme1425/img/light-bg-bottom.png);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```